# PySpark aggregation and complex schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a Spark dataframe (df1) like this:

```
deviceid   host      count 
a.b.c.d   0.0.0.0     1
a.b.c.d   1.1.1.1     3
x.y.z     0.0.0.0     2
```

I want to convert it into a new dataframe like this

```
deviceid   hosts_counts   
a.b.c.d    [(0.0.0.0,1),(1.1.1.1,3)]
x.y.z      [(0.0.0.0,2)]
```

What I have tried is this:

```
def convertTuple(*data): 
    for k,v in data: 
        return k[0], (k[1],v)  

df2 = df1.map(convertTuple) # zip host and count
```

Then:

```
function countReducer(a,b): 
    return a + b
df3 = df2.reduceByKey(countReducer)
```

However, that gives me a dataframe like this and I don't know how to go next to achieve my final goal:

[image: df3 Screenshot]

**Edit**

I managed to use  `groupby` and `collect_list`to solve this problem. The tricky part is in order to aggregate on the `(host,count)` tuple, you need to create a `strcut`. Here is the code:

```
df = df1.groupby("deviceid").agg(collect_list(struct("domain","count")).alias("domain_count"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are concating tuples together, the `countReducer` will not give you a list of tuples. In Python:

```
(1,2) + (3,4) = (1,2,3,4)
```

What you can do is to convert the tuple to an list of tuples (with a single element). It can be done by using a `map`:

```
.map(lambda x: (x[0], [ x[1] ]))
```

But in this case it would be better to change the `convertTuple` function to return what you want:

```
def convertTuple(*data): 
    for k,v in data: 
        return k[0], [(k[1],v)]
```

---

As a side note, it look like you are using RDDs and not dataframes. If you don't use an old Spark version I would recommend looking into changing to dataframes instead since they are a bit easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on the transformation part. In terms of the RDD/dataframe, I did use dataframe. I actually managed to use collect_list to achieve the same goal. I will update my post with my solution.